# Is the `layer` parameter in `UIView.layoutSublayers(of:)` always the view's layer?

Tags: ios, uiview, overriding, subclass, calayer

When overriding `layoutSublayers(of:)` in a UIView subclass, can I safely assume that the layer passed to the method will *always* be the UIView's layer?

If so, is this stated somewhere in the documentation (I've searched but didn't find any mention of that)?

---

To provide some context on why I'm asking: Inside an override of UIViews implementation of the CALayerDelegate method `layoutSublayers(of:)` in a custom UIView subclass, does it make sense to check if the layer is the views own layer like this:

```swift
class FooView: UIView {
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        guard layer === self.layer else { return }
    }
}
```

Or is this check redundant since Apple officially guarantees that (unless I personally change it) the view will *only* ever be the delegate of its own layer?

Answer (score 1):

`layoutSublayers(of:)` is *not* a UIView method. It is a CALayerDelegate method, called on the layer's delegate.

Well, you are certainly guaranteed that a UIView is the delegate of its CALayer, because that is how a UIView and its CALayer work. If that were not the case, drawing would break and the entire interface would stop working.

However, you cannot guarantee that the UIView is not *also* the delegate of some *other* layer! That would not happen by itself, but it would be possible for you to set things up that way. However, you never actually would! In my book, I warn against this:

> But be careful! Do *not*, under any circumstances, set the `delegate` of a layer that *is* the underlying layer of a UIView; and do *not* make a UIView the `delegate` of any layer other than its underlying layer. A UIView *must* be the delegate of its underlying layer; moreover, it must *not* be the delegate of any *other* layer. *Don't do anything to mess this up.* If you do, extremely bad things will happen; for instance, drawing will stop working correctly.

So yes, you may take it for granted that the layer in question is the view's layer.

Comment: I know that it's a method required by CALayerDelegate, but UIView does implement that method, thus I can override it in a custom subclass. Sorry for phrasing my question in an misunderstandable manner. I could've phrased it like that: "Is it guaranteed that a UIView is the delegate of *only* its own layer. Thanks for your answer and the quote from your book, is there anywhere in the documentation where Apple officially supports that view or have you come to that conclusion by testing?

Comment: Also, while it makes sense that it is the case, "because that is how a UIView and its CALayer work." does not have the same weight to me as an actual mention of that in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated [in the official documentation of CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW126):

> If the layer object was created by a view, the view typically assigns itself as the layer’s delegate automatically, and you should not change that relationship.

"Typically" is not a guarantee but makes it sound very likely that a UIView is always its own layer's delegate. Unfortunately, it is not stated there if a UIView can by default (i.e. as implemented in UIKit, without programmer intervention) also be another layer's delegate at the same time.

Comment: _Unfortunately, it is not stated there if a UIView can by default (i.e. as implemented in UIKit, without programmer intervention) also be another layer's delegate at the same time_ Well it never will be. And if you are in doubt, add a condition and check! But I’ve been doing this since iOS 3 and I’m sure of my ground even if you are not. :)

Comment: Currently, I'm always adding a condition (as can be seen in my edit). I was asking because I wanted to know if I can safely get rid of that condition. Thanks for sharing your experience :)